# How to execute my RETURN on my method until THREAD is procesed?

Tags: multithreading, methods, return

I have a method in my class that returns a STRING procesed on a thread and I need to wait to resolve the work on my thread until the RETURN is executed. Any idea to resolve it ?? Can I have a simple example for this ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If java then Callable interface was done exactly for this:

```
 class CalculateSomeString implements Callable<String>{
     @Override
     public String call() throws Exception {
         //Simulate some work that it takes to calculate the String
         Thread.sleep(1000);
         return "CoolString";
     }
 }
```

And the code that runs it

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    Future<String> future = service.submit(new CalculateSomeString());
    //this will block until the String has been computed
    String result = future.get();
    service.shutdown();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```